# SQL - Get the distinct record from the Group having common field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table : supplier_product

```
Product , Supplier, Status
Sugar   , N_Supp,   MAIN
Sugar   , S_Supp,   SUB
Sugar   , E_Supp,   MAIN
Water   , N_Supp,   SUB
Water   , S_Supp,   SUB
Water   , W_Supp,   SUB
Milk    , S_Supp,   MAIN
Milk    , N_Supp,   MAIN
Cream   , N_Supp,   SUB
Cream   , E_Supp,   SUB 
Coffee  , S_Supp,   MAIN 
Coffee  , W_Supp,   SUB
Coffee  , N_Supp,   SUB
```

I have to get all Products having only 'SUB' as the status.
I used this code. But I can't figure out the problem with my query, it has incorrect results

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.product
FROM supplier_product s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT
    *
FROM supplier_product
WHERE supplier_product.product = s.product
AND supplier_product.status = 'SUB')
```

It should get the result of:

```
Product
Water
Cream
```

Please help, if you have encountered this problem or any links/suggestions. I will be glad to learn about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is most easily done using aggregation:

```
select sp.product
from supplier_product sp
group by sp.product
having min(sp.status) = max(sp.status) and   -- the statuses are all the same
       min(sp.status) = 'SUB';               -- the value is 'SUB'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `HAVING` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT product
FROM supplier_product
GROUP BY product
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'SUB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 'SUB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/551754)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @Felix Pamittan, it is working. Thanks for the demo also. :D

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct product
from supplier_product
where status = 'SUB'
```